# PHP walking and print multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

anyone can help me with some coding here?

I got the following array config:

```
$array[1]['areaname'] = 'Area 1';
$array[1][1]['areaname'] = 'Sub Area 1';
$array[1][2]['areaname'] = 'Sub Area 2';
$array[1][3]['areaname'] = 'Sub Area 3';
$array[2]['areaname'] = 'Area 2';
$array[2][1]['areaname'] = 'Sub Area 1';
```

I want display the following:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Area 1
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Area 1</li>
            <li>Sub Area 2</li>
            <li>Sub Area 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        Area 2
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Area 1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need a code where I can have as many sub area as I want. Example:

```
$array[1][1][2][3][4]['areaname'];
```

There are also another condition. The array got other elements such as $array[1]['config'], $array[1][2][3]['link'] or $array[1][another array of elements that should not be into the loop] ... I only need print the areaname.

Comment: You should Google a bit on the subject of recursion. Learning it will serve you much better in the long run than a cut and paste solution.

Comment: Been trying and reading for a while, I can print it recursively doing it inside a function and calling it after the loop if the $value is an array, but the problem comes when printing the HTML. Could not find a solution to to close the UL's, or when close or not the LI's ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = array();
$array[1]['areaname'] = 'Area 1';
$array[1][1]['areaname'] = 'Sub Area 1';
$array[1][2]['areaname'] = 'Sub Area 2';
$array[1][3]['areaname'] = 'Sub Area 3';
$array[2]['areaname'] = 'Area 2';
$array[2][1]['areaname'] = 'Sub Area 1';

function generate_html_list_recursive( &$data, $labelKey )
{
    // begin with an empty html string
    $html = '';

    // loop through all items in this level
    foreach( $data as $key => &$value )
    {
        // where only interested in numeric items
        // as those are the actual children
        if( !is_numeric( $key ) )
        {
            // otherwise continue
            continue;
        }

        // if no <li> has been created yet, open the <ul>
        $html .= empty( $html ) ? '<ul>' : '';

        // extract the label from this level's array, designated by $labelKey
        $label = isset( $value[ $labelKey ] ) ? $value[ $labelKey ] : '';

        // open an <li> and append the label
        $html .= '<li>' . $label;

        // call this funcion recursively
        // with the next level ($value) and label key ($labelKey)
        // it will figure out again whether that level has numeric children as well
        // returns a new complete <ul>, if applicable, otherwise an empty string
        $html .= generate_html_list_recursive( $value, $labelKey );

        // close our currently open <li>
        $html .= '</li>';
    }

    // if this level has <li>'s, and therefor an opening <ul>, close the <ul>
    $html .= !empty( $html ) ? '</ul>' : '';

    // return the resulting html
    return $html;
}

echo generate_html_list_recursive( $array, 'areaname' );
```

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly. What is the reason using & on $data since with and without works perfectly.

Comment: @Henrique: the `&` means that the argument will be [passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), thereby not making unnecessary copies of the data. This would not be necessary for objects, as those would always be passed by reference.

Comment: this means when passing an array, it will only be copied the referenced elements in the function? Thanks,

Comment: @Henrique: no, it means nothing is copied at all (unless I misunderstood your question). It means you could edit `$array` directly inside the function. We don't need to touch the array inside the function, only read from it, but making a copy would still be unnecessary. (However, I forgot to add an `&` before `$value` as well, as `foreach()` makes a copy of the data as well; I've adjusted this now). For more information, read the article I linked to in my previous comment carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to [use array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) or [array_walk_recursive()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php).

Comment: Already tried that, but how to write the callback function when to open and close the UL's and LI's?